# Running a Fisher test on each row of a data frame in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame of ~50k measurements taken by ~3k investigators.

```
INVESTIGATOR_ID \\\ SAMPLE_ID \\\ MEASUREMENT
1000            \\\ 38942     \\\ 20.1
1000            \\\ 38942     \\\ 10.2
1001            \\\ 38432     \\\ 5.6
1002            \\\ 553       \\\ 10.6
...
```

My goal is to compare sample measurements per investigator to measurements from the entire data set:

1. For each investigator, count those measurements that are +/- one standard deviation from the measurement mean collected by that investigator.
2. For the entire data frame, count those measurements that are +/- one standard deviation from the mean.
3. For each investigator that has sample measurements +/- one standard deviation from the mean, run a Fisher's exact test to determine if the number of samples is significant (compared to the entire data frame).

I've used the Plyr library (`ddply`) to summarise the data by `INVESTIGATOR_ID`. Merging data together, the end result is a data frame, where each row consists of an investigator ID, the number of samples measured by that investigator, number of samples measured by that investigator +/- 1 SD, 15000, and 50000 (where 15000 and 50000 are the corresponding sample numbers +/- 1 SD and the total number of samples for the entire data frame).

```
INVESTIGATOR_ID \\\ NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES \\\ NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES_SD \\\ 15000 \\\ 50000
```

How do I take each row of the data frame, convert fields `c(2:5)` to a matrix, run a Fisher's test, and create a new data frame of the results?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that (adapted from a script of mine, could need more modifications to fit you needs):

```
get_fisher <- function(df){
  mat <- matrix(as.numeric(df[c(2:5)]), ncol=2)
  f <- fisher.test(as.table(mat), alt="two.sided")
  return(c(df[1], f$p.value))
}

fishers <- apply(df, 1,  get_fisher)
```