# fisher's test stat on data frame using dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How can one get test stats from a test in R, e.g. ´fisher.test()´ when applied to a whole data frame using selected columns. I know how to do manually, eg to grap the p.value:

```
fisher.test(matrix(c(9,0,1,1),ncol=2))$p.value
```

gives:

```
[1] 0.1818182
```

I need to do get p.value and estimate from `fisher.test()` on a data frame, and looking at [this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983579/running-a-fisher-test-on-each-row-of-a-data-frame-in-r) I got inspired to make a function like this:

```
fisher <- function(a,b,c,d){
  data <- matrix(c(a,b,c,d),ncol=2)
  c(p = fisher.test(data)$p.value,
    OR = fisher.test(data)$estimate)
}
```

This also works like:

```
fisher(9,0,1,1)[[1]]
```

and gives me the same as above. 
However, how to get this to work onto a data.frame, e.g. add a column named ´p´ using mutate ?

```
require(plyr)
require(dplyr)
data <- 
  data.frame(v1=c(9,10,2,2),
             v2=c(0,8,0,0),
             v3=c(1,1,0,9),
             v4=c(1,2,3,4))
data %>%
mutate(p=fisher(v1,v2,v3,v4)[[1]])
```

Does not work (it gives the same value for all rows). Do I need an ´apply´ somehow or can it be done with `dplyr::do` ?

Comment: What are you trying to perform the test on?  v1 vs. v2?  v1 + v2 vs. v3 + v4?  All combinations?

Comment: It should take v1 + v2 vs. v3 + v4 I guess

Answer (score 3):

Use ´rowwise()´ like this:

```
fisher <- function(a,b,c,d){
  data <- matrix(c(a,b,c,d),ncol=2)
  c(p = fisher.test(data)$p.value,
    OR = fisher.test(data)$estimate)
}
data %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(p=fisher(v1,v2,v3,v4)[[1]],
         OR=fisher(v1,v2,v3,v4)[[2]])
```

And - from the data above - we get:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4         p       OR
1  9  0  1  1 0.1818182      Inf
2 10  8  1  2 0.5864662 2.394164
3  2  0  0  3 0.1000000      Inf
4  2  0  9  4 1.0000000      Inf
```